# How to find number lower than key in set? C++

Tags: c++, set

I am new in C++ world.
There is a upper_bound function in a set that returns number greater than passed value. I would like to know if there is any way to get a number lower than the passed value? Let's say if we have {3,6,8,9,11} in set and by passing to my function: func(8), I will receive 6, since 6 is the number that stays before 8.
Any idea?

Comment: `std::upper_bound` (as well as `std::lower_bound`, which is more suitable here) returns an _iterator_. If this is _bidirectional_, you can iterate back to find your desired number.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is reasonable, but instead of `std::upper_bound`, you should use [std::lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/lower_bound/), like this for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    set<int> myset{3, 6, 8, 9, 11};

    set<int>::iterator it = myset.lower_bound(8);
    if (it != myset.begin()) {
        it--;
        cout << *it << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "No smaller element found!" << endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Ouptut:

> 6

Comment: I believe you mean `set::` not `std::`

Comment: Oh, intermixed `using namespace std` and `std` namespace declarations... I'd prefer [dropping the former](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @appleapple and Aconcagua good catch! Those were leftovers, which I've now removed! Although I agree with the link, IMHO `using namespace std;` in such small and compact examples allows the reader to focus on what matters.